# return result to parent function from async.parallel node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, controller

I'm very new to node.js and need help. I need to send save() result to controller, but it is isolated. I do not understand what is the way do do it properly. Should it be a callback (trying to understand how it works) or another solution. Can you please explain how to resolve it on a specific case?

Thank you.

Method called from the Controller:

```
    exports.createProduct = function (req) {

      async.parallel({
        // Search for genre existent id's sent from client
        genres: (callback) => {
          Genre.find({_id: {$in: req.body.genre}}, '_id').exec(callback);
        }
      }, (err, docs) => {
        // if (err) { throw err; }
        // Assign found genres
        req.body.genre = docs.genres;

        let product = new Product({
          title: req.body.title,
          description: req.body.description,
          images: req.body.images,
          genres: req.body.genre,
          price: req.body.price,
          status: req.body.status,
          sold: req.body.sold,
        });
        return product.save();
      });
      // return to Controller
    };
```

Comment: *I'm very new to node.js and need help* - I'd suggest to not make async.js your first option then, because it's dated. It can be fully replaced with promises. Mongoose (the question doesn't mention it) supports promises for a long time as well. It's unclear how `createProduct` is used. It's also unclear what your case is, you have single DB request, you wouldn't need `async.parallel` any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it passing a callback function for createProduct function like this

```
// Product module

exports.createProduct = function (req, callback) {

    async.parallel({
    // Search for genre existent id's sent from client
    genres: (callback) => {
      Genre.find({_id: {$in: req.body.genre}}, '_id').exec(callback);
    }
  }, (err, docs) => {
    // if (err) { throw err; }
    // Assign found genres
    req.body.genre = docs.genres;

    let product = new Product({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      images: req.body.images,
      genres: req.body.genre,
      price: req.body.price,
      status: req.body.status,
      sold: req.body.sold,
    });
    product.save();

    return callback(/* You can pass any params here*/);
  });
  // return to Controller
};


/// Controller module


const product = require('./lib/product');

exports.controllerFunction = () => {
    product.createProduct(req, (params) => {
        // Called when product is created
    })
}
```